# MS Access SQL Query - syntax error(missing operator) in query expression

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access, vbscript

I am trying to understand why my query(below) displays an error message in MS Access Sql query editor(sqlview) when I run it.

```
SELECT *
FROM tblUSPS
INNER JOIN   tblProductUSPS 
ON tblProductUSPS.[PRODUCTUSPS_USPS] = tblUSPS.[USPS_CODE] 
INNER JOIN  tblAttribute 
ON tblUSPS.USPS_ID = tblAttribute.ATTRIBUTE_USPSID
```

As far as I know the script below if I delete either of the INNER join lines. For instance, this script runs with no errors

```
SELECT *
FROM tblUSPS
INNER JOIN   tblProductUSPS 
ON tblProductUSPS.[PRODUCTUSPS_USPS] = tblUSPS.[USPS_CODE]
```

And so does this

```
SELECT *
FROM tblUSPS  
INNER JOIN  tblAttribute ON tblUSPS.USPS_ID = tblAttribute.ATTRIBUTE_USPSID
```

But when I combine, something goes wrong and I am unable to find it so I would like some help identifying this please.

Comment: Please try googling first, in this case "MS Access multiple inner joins" got me straight to what seems your problem:  http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/1617402-correct-syntax-inner-join-multiple-tables.html  I mean honestly, SO should not be your first stop for all problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access 2010: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852499/access-2010-syntax-error-missing-operator-in-query-expression)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Access has strong opinions on parentheses.

```
SELECT *
  FROM 
(tblUSPS
INNER JOIN   tblProductUSPS 
   ON tblProductUSPS.[PRODUCTUSPS_USPS] = tblUSPS.[USPS_CODE] )
INNER JOIN  tblAttribute 
   ON tblUSPS.USPS_ID = tblAttribute.ATTRIBUTE_USPSID
```

Comment: Thanks. I was following the tutorial on w3schools and it did not mention that. Thanks

Comment: If you're learning SQL then I strongly recommend you do not learn it in Access.  Oracle, SQL Server have free products and mySQL is completely free.

Comment: For the complete beginner, Access has the query design window that allows you to build joins with drag and drop, in addition there are a number of wizards. You can then switch to sql view to get a good idea of how to build your own queries.