# correlated sub query

Tags: sql, ms-access, correlated-subquery

Trying to show customers' vehicles who had an invoice raised in the past 30 days. 
I tried this:

```
select C.*, V.*
from CAR_OWNERSHIP O
join VEHICLE V on v.VEH_ID = O.VEH_ID
join CUSTOMER C on C.CUS_ID = O.CUS_ID
where exists (select null
              from INVOICE I
              where I.INV_ID = O.INV_ID and
                    I.INV_DATE >= date() - 30);
```

Im getting "syntax error in FROM clause"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have quickly tried a query in access and I get the same error you get but when I change the JOIN to a specific join like LEFT OUTER JOIN or INNER JOIN then that error goes away but it is replaced with another

```
 Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression in
```

I researched that and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852499/access-2010-syntax-error-missing-operator-in-query-expression) which indicates that access requires parentheses when using more than one join

```
select *
from (CAR_OWNERSHIP O
left outer join CUSTOMER C on C.CUS_ID = O.Cus_ID)
left outer join VEHICLE V on v.VEH_ID = O.VEH_ID
where exists (select null
          from INVOICE I
          where I.INV_ID = O.INV_ID and
                I.INV_DATE >= date() - 30);
```

I do hope this helps

Comment: Hey kleinkie, this solved the problem. Thank you very much. I realized that i need to narrow down the select a bit though, im geeting too many attributes. Other than that though its perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, I was trying to find a way to PM you but I don't see how. I was wondering if you might have the time to maybe explain this query to me. The query was recommend to me and I understand what the result is. I just don't think I fully understand what each line does. If you have the time. I understand the Select * and from Ownership. The rest im not 100% on.

Comment: Car_Ownership is your intersection entity that resolves the many to many between the Customer and Vehicle relation. In order to retrieve the combined data between the three tables, you need to "JOIN" the data. To find out more about the different joins you can read up on it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208894(v=office.12).aspx

The EXISTS returns a single true/false value although I've never used it as you have here. I assume that the resultset will be filtered if there are invoices meeting the criteria but I don't know if it is going to return what you need.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you are combining the ownership table with customer and then the result of that with vehicle. The syntax "on C.CUS_ID = O.Cus_ID" I assume this is used to identify the referential integrity, same of vehicle. The "select null" does that mean, we're not looking for anything to be selected in the sub-query, its used  as a conditional operation, but a Select, Delete, Update, etc is required to start the statement?

Comment: I guess the relation between invoice ID from ownership and invoice must be stated before we can find narrow it down by the date. I ran the query without "I.INV_ID = O.INV_ID and", what I got was all the invoices. Im not sure why.

Comment: Yes you are combining the data in the tables. You are joining on columns that link the tables together. I am not sure why you are selecting NULL persay but the subquery where clause is finding all invoices that are equal to the invoices returned in the parent resultset (I.INV_ID = O.INV_ID where O is the Car_Ownership table) I would assume that the SELECT NULL should be SELECT 1 although I have never used such a clause before. I would suggest playing around with it and researching it further.